# How to update a class member?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to update the filename variable by calling a method called select_file(). I then wanted to pass this value to a controller class. But by now I'm stuck with maintaining the chosen value even in the Form class, because it's still None in the line where the print() method is.

```
class Form:
    def select_file(self):
        filetypes = [('MP3', '*.mp3'), ('WAV', '*.wav')]
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)

    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = None

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("test")
        root.geometry('600x400')

        button = ttk.Button(
            root, 
            text = 'Open', 
            command = self.select_file)

        button.place(x = 260, y = 190)

        print(self.filename)

        root.mainloop()
```

I expected this code to work because wherever I'm refering to the filename variable I use the self attribute. So it shouldn't be understood as a local variable for one method, but as a variable which is local for the whole class. Am I right?

Comment: what is `fd` in your code? You are calling its method on `fd.askopenfilename()`

Comment: You've configured a button to run `select_file`, but have to click the button before it does, so at the point of the `print` `self.filename` is still `None`.

Comment: @Rafael fd is for filedialog from tk inter, sorry for not specifying that

Comment: @MarkTolonen do you mean I should set onClick event for this button? I thought command argument takes care of that.